# Split string of folder path

Tags: javascript, regex, string

If I have a file path such as:

```
var/www/parent/folder
```

How would I go about removing the last folder to return:

```
var/www/parent
```

The folders could have any names, I'm quite happy using regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NodeJS or browser environment? NodeJS has the [Path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following regular expression to match the last directory part, and replace it with empty string.

```
/\/[^\/]+$/
```

---

```
'var/www/parent/folder'.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '')
// => "var/www/parent"
```

**UPDATE**

If the path ends with `/`, the above expression will not match the path. If you want to remove the last part of the such path, you need to use folloiwng pattern (to match optional last `/`):

```
'var/www/parent/folder/'.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/?$/, '')
// => "var/www/parent"
```

Comment: the first one worked as i do not add a "/" on the end. Thanks an sorry it made me wait 5 mins until i could accept as answer :/

Answer (score 19):

use the split->slice->join function:

```
"var/www/parent/folder".split( '/' ).slice( 0, -1 ).join( '/' );
```

Comment: Much easier to be remembered than the regex solution.

Answer (score 8):

This is no specialized version of `split` per se, but you can split by the `path.sep` like so:

```js
import path from 'path';

filePath.split(path.sep);
```

Comment: As mentioned in the Node.js documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep

Answer (score 4):

If it's always the *last* folder you want to get rid of, the easiest method would be to use `substr()` and `lastIndexOf()`:

```
var parentFolder = folder.substr(0, folder.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dvtzp0tu/)**